# How can I get livereload working for my express app?

Tags: angularjs, express, livereload

Currently running an angular+express app. Trying to implement a livereload but without success. This is the server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var livereload = require('livereload')

livereload = require('livereload');
server = livereload.createServer();
server.watch(__dirname + "/scripts");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));

app.get("/hello", function(req, res) {
    console.log('api hello');
    res.send("Hello worldjjjjhjhjh");
});

var server =app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('listening on port ',server.address().port);
});
```

The app runs fine but when I change the angular code there is no reload , the browser does not reload? This is the link to github, checkout the livereload branch: https://github.com/dimitri-a/simpleng/tree/livereload.

Answer (score 0):

check if the application does not run on production mode, that worked for me.